# Can't open next ViewController - *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished]

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm having this issue only for login process. In current controller connect with the external database  (after add username and password ) and and after get the response application should dismiss current controller and should open next view Controller. I'm getting server response correctly.

```
let postString  = “lgn=sedr&UNAME=\(userName)&PASSWORD=\(password)"

let request=NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:url)!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler:{ ( data,response,error) -> Void in

    print(NSThread.isMainThread())

    if error != nil {
        // print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    var parsingError: NSError?

    if let dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,options: nil,error: &parsingError) as NSDictionary? {

        println("dic: \(dictionary)")

        if var suc:AnyObject=dictionary["success"] {

            println("success: \(suc)")

            if((suc as AnyObject! as Int)==1) {

                if let userID  = dictionary["userId"] {

                    println("userid: \(userID)")
                    //Save data

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("true",forKey:"isLogged");
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userID,forKey:"userID");
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();


                    var storyboard: UIStoryboard =   UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    var vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BControllerID") as UIViewController

                    self.presentViewController(vc ,animated: true, completion: nil )
                } else {
                    self.displayErrorAlert("Oops! Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

task.resume();
```

This is the error log I got :

```
2016-12-12 14:14:42.911 appService[39180:1705287] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374

2016-12-12 14:14:42.917 appService[39180:1705287] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
```

I have few more controllers do similar process but I only get this exception for this controller.

As found from the internet this error happen due to not present relevant asserts and not using the main thread for UI updates. I checked all components and all of them are present. I think this is because of not using the main thread. But I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to call new controller on main thread, not on the background thread.Currently the block in which you are presenting the view in not on main thread. Use dispatch queue which presenting the view controller like this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
var storyboard: UIStoryboard =   UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BControllerID") as UIViewController

self.presentViewController(vc ,animated: true, completion: nil )
}
```

or in swift 3 like this :

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
 //your block of code
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for support.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the main thread needs to be used instead of the background thread? Seems a bit arbitrary. Thanks for your help

Comment: Because the changes in the UI needs to done on the main thread else the reaction time will slow down and will seem sluggish. Changing it to the main thread will prioritise the action thus leading to utilize the more time from processor.